# Using Python and OpenCv to sequentially display all the images in a directory

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to use OpenCV's python bindings to sequentially display all of the images in a directory.

This code prints all the files in my directory but only displays the first image it opens:

```
for file in os.listdir(path):
  print(file)

  image = cv2.imread(os.path.join(my_dir, 'attachments',
  file))

  cv2.imshow("Image", image)
  cv2.waitKey(550)
```

What do I need to change so that every image in my directory is displayed by cv2.imshow? My print statement shows me that I am looping through all of my images but imshow is not being redrawn through any but the first iteration of my loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**

**If you want to see all your images in different windows:**

The other thing that occurred to me is that you may want to give each of your `cv2.imshow()` commands a different name other than "Image". With different names, you can have multiple imshow windows. So you could do:

```
for indx, f in enumerate(os.listdir(path), start=1):
    image = cv2.imread(os.path.join(my_dir, 'attachments', f))  
    cv2.imshow("Image-{}".format(indx), image)
    cv2.waitKey(600)
```

**EDIT 2:**

I went back to double check my answer and realized that your code seems to work just fine for me... I'm using opencv '3.0.0'

Comment: I've tried changing my waitkey value and I tried adding your code to change the name of my windows. Neither solves my problem. Only the first image in my directory is loaded by imshow.

Comment: can you try `print(image)` after the `cv2.imread()` function to make sure there aren't any `None` values or anything else weird like that?

Comment: print(image) after cv2.imread() gives me a bunch of multidimensional lists. I can't quite tell if they are the same lists repeated over and over.

Comment: Hmm.. you can do `print(type(image))`

Comment: My code works as expected for you? I'm using opencv "3.0.0" as well. I'm not sure why imgshow doesn't load any but the first of my pics.

Comment: print(type(image)) gives me <type 'numpy.ndarray'>

Comment: Well you've stumped me :(. The only other thing I might try would be: `cv2.destroyWindow("Image")` after the `cv2.waitKey()`...

Comment: If this whole `cv2.imshow()` thing doesn't work out for you, you can always use matplotlib see: http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_image_display/py_image_display.html#using-matplotlib